Is operating on female patient in this specific condition haram?
I am a MD radiologist. To give some context I live in a non Muslim majority country. I work in a hospital 6 days a week. In our department there are 5 radiologist including me. Only 1 of them is female and rest all are male. And I am the only muslim there. I chose radiology because I had a good rank and it is also the top sought profession with a small closing rank.
Now our typical day involves CT scan, MRI, USG not only of pregnancy but also to evaluate organs like the liver, gallbladder, kidneys, and pancreas, to examine muscles, tendons, and joints, Vascular ultrasound,Thyroid ultrasound, Pediatric ultrasound, Cardiac ultrasound (echocardiogram), Prostate ultrasound, Other Ultrasound-guided procedures. Now we do have a good patient load hence everyone is busy. For female reproductive part disease related and breast related issues the female radio handles it almost 99% of time and also there is patient preference in this case. Rest work is done by division of labour.
Now as far as how work is concerned there is a male and a female attendent for respective genders regardless of the doctor's gender they do all covering, uncovering positioning, etc. We keep a device on belly(for ultrasonography) or the parts(for other disorders, not pelvis and breast for me) and it captures the image(so no direct physical contact), I study and report. A or two family member is always present and the attended is also there for full time.
I always keep my gaze lowered, don't look anything more or less than what area is required, nor go in excess talking with women. Sometimes there is emergency for female patients and I by duty have to attend it(we have divided work load).
Am I sinful for operating on female patients, like ultrasonography or say artery blockage in hand, broken bone or blockage in back?

I understand that gender is not important or considered in medical field, as you are doing service to patient. As long as the patient do not have issue, you can do the service to them. Helping a person is charity work in Islam

Firstly, an emergency situation differs from a normal situation. In an emergency, if a doctor of the same gender is not available, it can be forgiven by Allah.
In non-emergency situations, looking at the body of a non-Mahram woman is considered haram and should be avoided. For instance, you might discuss with your manager the possibility of operating exclusively on same-gender patients. If that is not feasible, another option could be immigration. Immigration does not solely refer to moving from one country to another; it can also involve relocating from one city to another or changing jobs workplaces.

إِنَّ الَّذِينَ تَوَفَّاهُمُ الْمَلَائِكَةُ ظَالِمِي أَنفُسِهِمْ
قَالُوا فِيمَ كُنتُمْ قَالُوا كُنَّا مُسْتَضْعَفِينَ فِي الْأَرْضِ
قَالُوا أَ لَمْ تَكُنْ أَرْضُ اللَّهِ وَاسِعَةً فَتُهَاجِرُوا فِيهَا
فَأُولٰئِكَ مَأْوَاهُمْ جَهَنَّمُ وَ سَاءَتْ مَصِيرًا  4/97/
That those the angels make them die, unjust (to) themselves, they
said: "In what you were/have been?" They said: "We were weakened in
the Earth/land." They said: "Was not God's Earth/land wide/spacious so
you emigrate in it." So those, their shelter/refuge (is) Hell, and it
was a bad/evil end/destination.(4:97)


As I have completed my qualification and at my 30s and have acquired specialization in this field it is almost impossible to do so. Is there any restriction that can be applied because ultrasond for pregnancy is a majority work and bound work in this field? Moreover in medical school we look at both male and female body parts so won't it be haram that time too, we also have compulsory internship for all specialities for one year to treat patients in almost all countries

@MadMan Generally, it is considered Haram for a man to look at the body of non-Mahran women. Paradise is precious, and we can reflect on the sacrifices made by Imam Hussain (a.s.) in his quest to please Allah.
